# Excel lookup match date product

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two spreadsheets:

S1 is a product list detailing column A the product and column B the price.

S2 is a list of separate transactions detailing column A the date, column B the product and column C the quantity sold.

In S1 I want to be able to enter a single date in cell C1 and in cell C2 I need a formula to match A2 the product against all of S2 column B and return the total of the quantity sold in S2 column C but only on the date in S1 cell C1.

Comment: Can you provide us with a small selection of sample data?

Comment: Sounds like you need `SUMIF()` or a Pivot Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can multiply the price by the result of a Sumifs formula that adds the products sold on a specific date. With the workbook and sheet structure you describe above, the formula would be along the lines of

```
=SUMIFS('S2'!C:C,'S2'!A:A,'S1'!$C$1,'S2'!B:B,'S1'!A2)*'S1'!B2
```

Screenshot of S1:

[image]

Screenshot of S2:

[image]

Comment: I was being silly and got my range and criteria turned around... thank you ever so much!